# Eclipse discord bot - problem with sending DMs's

Tags: javascript, eclipse

So im creating a discord bot for fun on my server, and one of the things im trying to do is send a DM to the sender of the Msg if the msg contains my name. However, i've tried various approaches, using various commands but nothing seems to work. Ive looked on the internet for the answer but I havent seen anyone using eclipse to make the bot, so their Code doesnt always work for me (Unless im just doing something wrong). Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Eclipse is just an IDE, how would it matter to a program not working?

Comment: Thats the thing, I dont know. Ive tried fixing my problem using the methods other people suggested on different posts, but when I try it in my code, it just breaks.

Comment: Ok, I'll get back to you with a sample code of how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some regex to search for your name being present in the message.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  let text = message;
  const containsName = text.search(/name/i); 

  /* search method returns the index of the first letter of the 
     string you're searching for if it is found, else returns -1. 
     Here we are using regex to search for the name, and the 'i' makes 
     it case insensitive.
  */

  if(!(containsName === -1)) message.author.send("whatever you want to DM");
});
```

Your name goes in place of the name in the regex.
More about regex, [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).